# Adding increment of 5 days to date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date-arithmetic

I am simply trying to add an additional 5 days to a date in my query. For instance, if my data in my `LastDate` column on my table has `2013-03-31` as its date, then adding 5 days should bring it up in my query because its a greater date then what is below. It won't come up and I've confused as to why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SELECT * FROM `ts_inventory` 
WHERE `ts_inventory`.`Quantity` > 0 
AND `ts_inventory`.`LastDate` > DATE_ADD(2013-01-22, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your date:

```
DATE_ADD(2013-01-22, INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

should be

```
DATE_ADD('2013-01-22', INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Comment: Thanks! echo was first, but I do appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

you should use quotes around the date.

try this

```
 SELECT * FROM `ts_inventory` 
 WHERE `ts_inventory`.`Quantity` > 0 
AND `ts_inventory`.`LastDate` > DATE_ADD('2013-01-22', INTERVAL 5 DAY)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need quotes around the date to make it a valid date variable.

i.e. `DATE_ADD('2013-01-22', INTERVAL 5 DAY)`

EDIT: ninja'ed.